# how to interpret my box-plot and p-value, since my plot gives significant difference but my p-value is greater than 0.05

Tags: plot

so i have two groups A and B and i want to find the differences between the two groups. I used two sample t-test and output my result graphically through box-plot. My problem is, the box-plot shows differences between the two groups but my p-value is P>0.05 (meaning no significant difference). Please could anyone help be understand my results.

Thanks

Comment: This question would be a better fit for http://stats.stackexchange.com - you probably did derive the plots using a programming language, but this is about interpreting them. It would also benefit from a picture of your box plots.

Comment: You should definitely go to a more specific stack exchange like Companynerd255 suggested.